# Unable to sort datetime using variable computed from datetime string

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to sort a table by datetime in descending order. I currently am trying to use a variable to be the field to be used in sorting.

Example data:

| header A | datetime |
| --- | --- |
| First | 01 Jan 2021 |
| Second | 17 Aug 2021 |

I created a variable, as seen below,to try to sort the records.
[image: intiail value expression]

[image: properties]

After creating the Long variable from the DATEVALUE expression, after converting to string, it shows null when I load it into preview. Also, it does not sort properly after using it as a sort field.

Some help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should post small *jrxml* to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

The dataset included the epoch of the date. I used that to sort.